# How to sign/log out on this website?

Tags: support

How do you do it? I don't see a "sign/log out" button anywhere. The quality thing is really annoying right now.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Nothing more to say really.

Comment: -1 missing a hand drawn red circle ;-)

Comment: Also: not super accessible to folks who use screen readers.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty That’s a good point.  Honestly I would not know how to write a set of instructions that would solve the issue you raise.  Maybe someone can teach me how it’s done (in terms of syntax etc.)

Comment: @Zero I'll try to write some up when my level of mental capacity goes back above "hey, you should re-take that screenshot when you get to 23,456 rep".

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It’s a nice screenshot...  That being said: how *does* one log off using a screen reader anyways...